# Picker Wheel in Corona not appearing at all

Tags: lua, coronasdk, picker

So I would like to make a multiple wheeled picker, such that

```
dataWheel1 = {"Standard", "Inverse Standard", "Hyperbolic", "Inverse Hyperbolic"}  
dataWheel2 = {"Sine", "Cosine", "Tangent", "Secant", "Cosecant", "Cotangent"}
```

So I do the following:

```
local storyboard = require( "storyboard" )
local scene = storyboard.newScene()

function scene:createScene( event )
    local group = self.view

    local bg = display.newRect( 0, 0, display.contentWidth, display.contentHeight )
    bg:setFillColor( 255 )

    local widget = require "widget"

    local columnData = {}

    columnData[1] = {"Standard", "Inverse Standard", "Hyperbolic", "Inverse Hyperbolic"}
    columnData[1].alignment = "right"
    columnData[1].width = 120
    columnData[1].startIndex = 7

    columnData[2] = {"Sine", "Cosine", "Tangent", "Secant", "Cosecant", "Cotangent"} 
    columnData[2].startIndex = 2

    local picker = widget.newPickerWheel{
    id="myPicker",
    font="Helvetica-Bold",
    top=258,
    columns=columnData
    }

    group:insert( picker.view )
    group:insert( bg )
end

function scene:enterScene( event )
    local group = self.view
end

function scene:exitScene( event )
    local group = self.view
end

function scene:destroyScene( event )
    local group = self.view
end

scene:addEventListener( "createScene", scene )

scene:addEventListener( "enterScene", scene )

scene:addEventListener( "exitScene", scene )

scene:addEventListener( "destroyScene", scene )

return scene
```

This shows up on the simulator as a blank page. I'm completely lost as to what is wrong or how to make it right.

Any help would be greatly appreciated, thanks.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Have a look at this [example](http://developer.coronalabs.com/reference/index/widgetnewpickerwheel). I think you need to this:

```
 local varName = require "widget"
```